# Query sharded collection returns all the results from the primary shard AND from the other shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.6

I tried to set up a shard to test this functionality and maybe migrate some of our data into it.

I followed the documentation guide https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/

So I have a first replica rs0 (containing 2 servers), a replica rs1 (containing 2 servers) and a config replica (containing 2 servers for my tests, I understand I should use at least 3 in production)

Now, when I'm connecting on mongos instance, I see that rs0 is my primary shard. And the collection I sharded contains 1,000,000 documents. rs1 contains 1 chunk which contains approximately 500,000 documents. If I execute db.partitioned_collection.count() in mongos it returns 1,500,000. Whereas I would expect it to return 1,000,000.

I get that the primary shard contains all the unsharded documents, but mongos should only query data inside rs0 chunks no ?

What am I doing wrong ?

My sh.status() result is :

```
--- Sharding Status ---
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5b992a952e6c702f9dd5b675")
}
shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/mongo-test:27017,mongo-test:27018",  "state" : 1 }
    {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/mongo-test:27019,mongo-test:27020",  "state" : 1 }
active mongoses:
    "3.6.7" : 1
autosplit:
    Currently enabled: yes
balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
            2 : Success
databases:
    {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
            config.system.sessions
                    shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            rs0     1
                    { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
    {  "_id" : "test",  "primary" : "rs0",  "partitioned" : true }
            test.partitioned_collection
                    shard key: { "number" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            rs0     2
                            rs1     1
                    { "number" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "number" : 4794 } on : rs1 Timestamp(2, 0)
                    { "number" : 4794 } -->> { "number" : 9586 } on : rs0 Timestamp(2, 1)
                    { "number" : 9586 } -->> { "number" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 2)
```

**UPDATE #1 :**

It seems I completely misread the following documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard . Indeed the primary shard does not hold the unsharded ***documents*** but the unsharded ***collections*** ...

So the question now is why my primary shard (rs0) which should only contains 2 chunks, is still containing the whole collection data ?

Comment: The [primary shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard) for a db only refers to ownership of unsharded collections. Since `partitioned_collection` is sharded, it is eligible to have data on multiple shards. `mongos` should be returning the count of unique documents across all shards (`rs0` has 2 chunks and `rs1` has 1). I notice you are referring to 3.4 docs but the question has a `mongodb-3.6` tag. What is your specific MongoDB server version as reported by `db.version()`? Also, are you using any secondary read preferences when querying via `mongos`?

Comment: I posted the wrong link, sorry, my version as returned by ```db.version()``` is 3.6.7.

I'm not using any read preference, I'm querying my collection with the exact following commands : 

```mongo --port 27030```
```use test```
```db.partitioned_collection.count()```

Comment: I think I might understand what's happening. My test (count all documents) is probably not a great one, because the query is bot using the shard key. Should every querys done to the shard collection have the shard key as a filter ?

I think so, based on the query plan I analyzed, because if I know try the query ```db.peoples.find({number:3000})``` I don't get the data in rs0 counted.

Comment: Well, I'm still having an issue on this, after studying query plans it seems that if the winning plan stage is ```SHARD_MERGE```, it will count documents twice. Whereas if the stage is ```SINGLE_SHARD```, it will give me the correct count.

Thus, ```db.partitioned_collection.find({number:3000})``` is giving me the correct count, whereas ```db.partitioned_collection.find({"number":{$in[4790, 4800]}}).count()``` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tested again to follow exactly the example at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/ . And this time it did work... It took some time (don't know how much exactly) for rs0 to delete the moved documents, but after a few minutes (or tens of minutes) they were not there anymore.

I have tried to remember what I did differently on the first time. I'm wondering if I did insert the test data after rs0 became a part of the shard directly on the rs0 replica set. And from what I understand we must not insert/update data on shard replica sets directly.

Comment: Inserting documents directly into the replica set backing a sharded collection is definitely one way to skew the counts in MongoDB 3.6 -- this can create orphaned documents that aren't expected to be found on the shard. You could fix this by running the  [`cleanupOrphaned` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cleanupOrphaned) on an affected `mongod` primary.

Comment: NOTE: the behaviour for counts on sharded collections with a query predicate (as per your examples) has been improved in MongoDB 4.0 and newer, so orphaned documents are now ignored. See [SERVER-3645](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645) in the MongoDB issue tracker for more background.